# Convergence of a Sequence: Guessing the limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I do have a problem with the limit of a sequence.

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence. If we take $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$, it's pretty obvious that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = 0$

The way I'd proof it would be as following:

Given $\epsilon > 0$, $$|a_n - a| < \epsilon \Leftrightarrow \left|\frac{1}{n^2} - a\right| < \epsilon$$

Here is my problem: 'Guess' it's limit $a = 0$

$$\left|\frac{1}{n^2} - 0\right| < \epsilon\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{n^2} < \epsilon \Leftrightarrow \sqrt\frac{1}{\epsilon} <  {n}$$

$\Rightarrow n_o = \lfloor \sqrt\frac{1}{\epsilon} \rfloor + 1$

$\forall _{n \geqslant n_0}$  $ |a_n - a| < \sqrt\frac{1}{\epsilon}$

My question is: is guessing the limit what you have to do?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, yes, since it is a very simple function and the limit is quite intuitive. For some other functions the limit is not that obvious, and you need to work a little bit more to prove it, e.g., $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x}x = 1$.

Your proof is right, but not well written. I'd suggest you "hide" all the calculations you did to find your $n_0$ and, when presenting the proof, write something like this:

---

Given $\epsilon > 0$, take $n_0 = \lfloor \sqrt{1/\epsilon} \rfloor + 1$. Therefore, for every $n \geq n_0$, we have $$\frac1{n^2} \leq \frac1{n_0^2} = \left(\sqrt{1/\epsilon}+1\right)^{-2} < \left(\sqrt{1/\epsilon}\right)^{-2} = \epsilon. $$

Comment: Could you please explain to me what would go wrong when we'd guess it's limit to be 1?

Comment: We just need to negate the definition of continuity, i.e., there is a $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, if $n \geq n_0$ then $|a_n - a| \geq \epsilon$. Since we already proved that the limit is $0$ and the limit of a real function is unique, then there is no such $n_0$ such that for every $n\geq n_0$, $|1/n^2 - 1| < \epsilon$.

Comment: This shows that if you guessed correctly then the answer is unique but if otherwise then it doesn't mean anything, the function could be continuous but you just got its limit wrong.

Comment: Your comment helped a bit, however [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/661901/384004) is what I meant with "what if my guess is wrong". Thank you for your help!

Comment: That was a mistake on the proof, you need to be careful with your statements. If all of your statements are correct the limit will be correct too.